# How to view JHipster Entity Database

Tags: mysql, database, entity, jhipster

I'm setting up a Web App with JHipster. I used JDL Entities to create my Domain Elements, while setting up JHipster i chose a MYSQL Database. Additionally i have an Android App and i want it to use the same Database as the Web App. How can i access the JHipster generated Database and do CRUD operations from another Application?

I found some Jhipster generator module https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-jhipster-administration-database

But the Database that i can view with this module has no tables when running on my App that already has Entities.

Comment: You can communicate with your JHipster app's backend through the REST api, similar to the Angular/React clients.  The way to do it depends on how you write your Android application.  For example here's one way to do it for React Native (which uses JS): https://github.com/ruddell/IgniteJhipsterSampleApp/blob/5b72aee01a0d4ac56f3fb0beca22d335d270811e/App/shared/services/api.js

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you wanna do. But usually we have 2 solution for that

1. Use seperate way to access database from android app. In that case, you have to build connect to your database by yourself, using ORM or event pure SQL query is up to you. So the answer is you have to write it by yourself. How to write is available in google.
2. Make android app using REST content provide by your web service. That is typical way i see in medium and big project. You can build a common back-end web service then using them for both web and android app through HTTP Request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i believe you showed me the right direction i needed. I know the question was pretty vague, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can create rest API's in your jhipster app and consume them on your android app

Comment: Looked in to it and it seems this is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks very much